# Filter User From Firebase AdminSDK

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

What I want to achieve here is, I should be able to pass phone numbers in an array and result should contain the user results matching with the phone number contained in the array.

Retrieving all the users are working just fine but I am not able to find out how to filter the results.

```
exports.listUsers = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
    // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
    const nextPageToken = req.query.token
    const mobileNumbers = req.query.phoneNumbers

    admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
        .then(function(listUsersResult) {
            listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {
                console.log('user', userRecord.toJSON());
            });

            if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
                // List next batch of users.
                listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
            }

            return res.send(listUsersResult);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Error listing users:', error);
        });
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by filter the results?

Comment: Right now, it is retrieving all the users from Firebase, I want to filter result based on the phone numbers provided in an array. Just like "IN" query in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Admin SDK provides APIs for [retrieving individual users by phone number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#getuserbyphonenumber) and [by email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#getuserbyemail). However, there is no batch retrieval API for filtering/querying all users by attributes such as `phoneNumber` or `email`.

## Workaround 1: [Retrieve all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) and filter

- Retrieve a list of all users
- Filter the list

## Workaround 2: Store users in another database

If filtering a large user base is a common operation for your app, then you can improve performance by storing users in a separate database.

- When new users sign-up, store the user information in another database such as Firestore, MySQL, PostgreSQL.
- Use standard query features to filter the results

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try Firestore but seems like it is also missing the IN query clause. I want to supply a list of phone numbers and it should return the users if it is present.